# Fail for Inner request caused fail of parent request

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I build `Jquery Promise`.
It's structure is next :

```
request1()
   .then(response => {})
   .then( () => {
      request2().done(response => {})
   }
   .fail(err => {});
```

In `done` and `fail` block I make "unblock" of screen. But sometimes I can't get "unblock" code.

Does it mean that something bad happens in `request2` and this bad isn't resolved in `fail` of parent request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you need to return the promise in the second then:

```
.then( () => {
    return request2().done(response => {})
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't use a block, the return is made automatically in ES6 lambda.

```
.then( () => request2().done(response => {}) )
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, seems like logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fail` and `done` callbacks aren't on the same promise. `request1()` and `request2()` create their own.

```
var deferred = request1();

deferred.then(response => {})
        .then(() => {
           request2().done(deferred.resolve)
                     .fail(deferred.reject)
        })
        .done(response => {})
        .fail(err => {});
```